# How to disable bang operator (!) in property initialization in js/ts

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint, eslintrc

Since I have set `strict: true` style rule, I will get the `Property has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts(2564)` error if I don't set initiation on a variable. I am able to bypass the error by adding bang operator ("!") after the variable name. For example, `test!: string;`.

However, I would like to avoid using the bang operators. Is it possible to force developers to use `test: string | undefined;` instead?

I tried `@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion": "error"`, but it didn't report errors for bang operators in property initialization. Any ideas?

Comment: but `test!: string` is not equivalent to `test: string | undefined`, the whole point of `!` is to *'assert that its operand is non-null and non-undefined'*

Comment: You can try filing an issue with the *no-non-null-assertion* package since it seems this should indeed be covered by the rule

Comment: You can try cooking up your own rule by [restricting that syntax](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-restricted-syntax)

Comment: @bergi do you mind providing an example and posting your answer? Thank you.